# UPDATE ordered by values in source and destination tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Consider following sample:

```
DECLARE @UPD TABLE
(KeyToFillIn Int,
SomeDataToCompare Int,
Ordinal Int)

DECLARE @SRC TABLE
(KeyS Int,
SomeDataToCompare Int)

INSERT @UPD VALUES (NULL, 100, 1)
INSERT @UPD VALUES (NULL, 100, 2)
INSERT @UPD VALUES (NULL, 100, 3)
INSERT @UPD VALUES (NULL, 100, 4)

INSERT @SRC VALUES (12, 100)
INSERT @SRC VALUES (280, 100)
INSERT @SRC VALUES (232, 100)
INSERT @SRC VALUES (1, 100)
INSERT @SRC VALUES (121, 100)
INSERT @SRC VALUES (123, 100)
INSERT @SRC VALUES (128, 100)

-- This update
UPDATE @UPD
SET KeyToFillIn = S.KeyS
FROM @UPD U INNER JOIN @SRC S ON U.SomeDataToCompare = S.SomeDataToCompare

SELECT * FROM @UPD
SELECT * FROM @SRC
```

I need to update UPD.KeyToFillIn in order taken from SRC table. SRC table may not have corresponding records (matched by SomeDataToCompare). Or it may have more. But I want UPD table to be sorted by Ordinal and KeyToFillIn taken from KeyS also in order. So, resultset will look like

```
1   100 1 
12  100 2 
121 100 3 
123 100 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
;WITH UPD
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SomeDataToCompare ORDER BY Ordinal) AS RN
         FROM   @UPD),
     SRC
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SomeDataToCompare ORDER BY KeyS) AS RN
         FROM   @SRC),
     U
     AS (SELECT KeyToFillIn,
                KeyS
         FROM   UPD U
                INNER JOIN SRC S
                  ON U.SomeDataToCompare = S.SomeDataToCompare
                     AND S.RN = U.RN)
UPDATE U
SET    KeyToFillIn = KeyS

SELECT *
FROM   @UPD
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2324)

Answer (score 1):

may be this will also useful as per assumed data we can get this in simple update statement

```
UPDATE U SET KeyToFillIn = R.KeyS  from @UPD U
INNER JOIN (Select ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (PARTITION BY SomeDataToCompare ORDER BY KeyS) AS RN,
            KeyS,SomeDataToCompare 
                    from @SRC )R
ON R.RN = U.Ordinal

select * from @UPD
```

Comment: Jonathan, This is exactly how I actually did it, you are correct, Ordinal is always 1.2.3. But I accepted Martin's answer since I didn't mention this detail and he gave more generic solution.

Comment: @katit even though i'm inspired by martin answer..anyway solution has helped you in both the ways..every one have their own logic what suits you that's the perfect answer